# How to read data from a file into a hash-map (or other data structure) in Clojure?

Tags: file, clojure

Not quite sure where to start with this.
I have a big file of data which contains different values which all related to a certain thing (i.e data in column 1 would be the hour) the file is 15 columns wide. The file does not contain any column headings though, it is all just numeric data.

I need to read this data into a data type such as a hash map which would allow me to sort through it and query the data using things such as contains? as well as perform calculations.

I am unsure of how to do this as I am new to Clojure, any help would be appreciated.

My file is a txt file (saved as mydata.txt) and structured like so:

```
  1 23 25 -9  -0 1 1
  2 23 25 10 1 2 3
```

My code so far is:

```
(def filetoanalyse (slurp "mydata.txt"))
(zipmap [:num1 :num2 :num3 :num4 :num5 :num6 :num7] filetoanalyse)
```

It seems to associated the whole of the file with :num1 at current.

Comment: The question is a bit vague for this particular forum. StackOverflow is best for questions focused on a complete, self-contained code example and specific expectations.

Comment: An example line would be helpful, but check out https://github.com/clojure/data.csv which seems likely to provide some utility for your use case.

Comment: Your description of your data is too vague for us to really do anything with it, could you post an example? Preferably with an attempt at a solution?

Comment: added the file structure and code so far, hope that is more helpful. TIA.

Comment: @digit23 well, your question now has two reopen votes only needs one more vote to be reopened, so yeah :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function you can use to do what you're looking for:

```
(defn map-from-file [field-re column-names filename]
  (let [ lines  (re-seq #"[^\r\n]+" (slurp filename)) ]
    (map #(zipmap column-names (re-seq field-re %)) lines)))
```

You have to supply three arguments:

1. A regular expression to separate the fields in each row. For the data you've shown this can be `#"[^ ]+"`, or basically anything which isn't a blank is part of the field. If you've got simple comma-separated values with no complications such as embedded commas in the data or quoted field something like `#"[^,]+"` will work. Or if you want to only extract numeric characters something a bit more complex such as `#"[-0-9]+" will work.
2. A collection of column names to assign.
3. The name of the file.

So if the data you show in your question is stored as `test3.dat` somewhere you could invoke the above function as

```
(map-from-file #"[^ ]+" [:c1 :c2 :c3 :c4 :c5 :c6 :c7] "/some-path/test3.dat")
```

and it would return

```
({:c1 "1", :c2 "23", :c3 "25", :c4 "-9", :c5 "-0", :c6 "1", :c7 "1"} {:c1 "2", :c2 "23", :c3 "25", :c4 "10", :c5 "1", :c6 "2", :c7 "3"})
```

or in other words you get back a sequence of maps which map the values by the column names you've supplied. If you prefer to have the data in a vector you can use

```
(into [] (map-from-file #"[^ ]+" [:c1 :c2 :c3 :c4 :c5 :c6 :c7] "/some-path/test3.dat"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This has really helped me :)

Comment: Beware: slurp will load the whole file as a string  into memory. If you have a particularly large files this is not a good idea. In such cases it's better to read a file line by line, using line-seq

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're running into is that `slurp` reads in the file as a string. When you use `zipmap` on it, it uses characters from the string as the values in the map, leading to this mess:

```clj
(zipmap [:num1 :num2 :num3 :num4 :num5 :num6 :num7] (slurp "mydata.txt"))
;;=> {:num1 \space,
      :num2 \space,
      :num3 \1,
      :num4 \space,
      :num5 \2,
      :num6 \3,
      :num7 \space}
```

The easiest approach is to iterate over the file line by line, splitting it into the values that you want. Note the `vec` here, which forces the result of the (lazy) `for`, ensuring that we process the entire file before `with-open` closes the reader.

```clj
(with-open [reader (clojure.java.io/reader "mydata.txt")]
  (vec (for [line (line-seq reader)]    ; iterate over each line
         (->> (clojure.string/split line #"\s+") ; split it by whitespace
              (remove empty?)           ; remove any empty entries
              (map #(Long/parseLong %)) ; convert into Longs (change if another format is more suitable)
              (zipmap [:num1 :num2 :num3 :num4 :num5 :num6 :num7]))))) ; turn into a map
```

Answer (score 2):

**Main answer**

Slurp will return the file contents as a text string, but your code seems to assume that this file has already been parsed into an array of numbers. That is not the case. You can still use `slurp` but you will have to parse the file yourself. You can parse it by first splitting the file string by line separator using [split-lines](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/split-lines). Each line is valid Clojure syntax for a vector if we surround it by square brackets, and if we do so, we can then parse it into a vector using [edn/read-string](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.edn/read-string). We use `map` to parse each line of the file. The following code will do the job, and uses the [->>](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) macro to keep the code readable:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as cljstr])
(require '[clojure.edn :as edn])

(->> "/tmp/mydata.txt"
     slurp
     cljstr/split-lines
     (map #(zipmap
            [:num1 :num2 :num3 :num4 :num5 :num6 :num7]
            (edn/read-string (str "[" % "]")))))
;; => ({:num1 1, :num2 23, :num3 25, :num4 -9, :num5 0, :num6 1, :num7 1} {:num1 2, :num2 23, :num3 25, :num4 10, :num5 1, :num6 2, :num7 3})
```

**Extensions/variations**

In case there are lines with other number of elements, you may want to keep only those with seven elements, using `filter`. Mapping and filtering can be composed into a [transducer](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers) that we pass as argument to [into](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into):

```
(let [columns [:num1 :num2 :num3 :num4 :num5 :num6 :num7]
      n (count columns)]
  (->> "/tmp/mydata.txt"
       slurp
       cljstr/split-lines
       (into [] (comp (map #(zipmap
                             columns
                             (edn/read-string (str "[" % "]"))))
                      (filter #(= n (count %)))))))
;; => [{:num1 1, :num2 23, :num3 25, :num4 -9, :num5 0, :num6 1, :num7 1} {:num1 2, :num2 23, :num3 25, :num4 10, :num5 1, :num6 2, :num7 3}]
```

If you expect to parse more complicated files or really wanted to kill/overengineer it, you could use [spec](https://clojure.org/guides/spec):

```
(require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as spec])

(->> "/tmp/mydata.txt"
     slurp
     cljstr/split-lines
     (map #(edn/read-string (str "[" % "]")))
     (spec/conform (spec/coll-of (spec/cat :num1 number?
                                           :num2 number?
                                           :num3 number?
                                           :num4 number?
                                           :num5 number?
                                           :num6 number?
                                           :num7 number?))))
;; => ({:num1 1, :num2 23, :num3 25, :num4 -9, :num5 0, :num6 1, :num7 1} {:num1 2, :num2 23, :num3 25, :num4 10, :num5 1, :num6 2, :num7 3})
```